# swaggerUI: fill X-AUTH-TOKEN apikey automatically

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I've got an apiKey in my swagger definition:

```
securityDefinition = @SecurityDefinition(
    apiKeyAuthDefinitions = {@ApiKeyAuthDefinition(
        key= "test",
        in = ApiKeyAuthDefinition.ApiKeyLocation.HEADER,
        name = "X-AUTH-TOKEN",
        description = "LHT-AM API KEY"
    )}
)
```

So SwaggerUI correctly offers authorization.

But how can i tell SwaggerUI to fill this authorization automatically from header?

Comment: What do you mean by "fill this authorization automatically" ?

Comment: I have to click the 'Authorize'-Button and enter the 'X-AUTH-TOKEN', I've extracted from a RequestHeader. I can't ask someone with limited IT-knowledge to do that.

Comment: So what's the purpose of the token if you are going to hardcode it in the UI? Maybe you don't need any authorization...

Comment: As far as I know SwaggerUI does not have that feature, but you can request it: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/new

Comment: The token is set by a sso service